# Health status on aws Elastic Beanstalk is red

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image]

I have created a simple java spring boot application and created a jar to host it on aws. The app simply displays "hello world" when the user enters http://localhost:8080/hello, so I wanted to turn it widely, but after severels attempts i simply get "red" flag on aws console.
I have configured the port at aws to listen on 5000
Thank you.

Comment: Have you inspected any events or logs?

Comment: no log is available on aws and "causes" under "Red" is disactivated so it's impossible to know why. I am thinking about the cause of the problem, from both the jar itself (created from eclipse by "export") as it's the first time i've done it and the aws method.

Comment: What do you mean? EB has event history you can inspect as well as you can download full logs from your instances from the EB console.

Comment: 30-09-2020 08:28:24 UTC+0200 
WARN
Environment health has been set to RED.

Comment: I've edited my initial post with the trace : everything seems ok, until it's a warn. There are no errors and no fatals.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is running on port 8080, but it should be on port 5000. As explained in the [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/):

> By default, Spring Boot applications will listen on **port 8080**. Elastic Beanstalk assumes that the application will listen on port **5000**. There are two ways to fix this discrepancy: change the port Elastic Beanstalk is configured to use, or change the port the Spring Boot application listens on. For this post, we will change the port the Spring Boot application listens on.

> The easiest way to do this is to specify the **SERVER_PORT environment variable** in the Elastic Beanstalk environment and set the value to 5000. (The configuration property name is server.port, but Spring Boot allows you to specify a more environment variable-friendly name).

Comment: it's a good remark but my instance is not even running properly, as it's red! first it's got to be green, then the listening port has to be configured.

Comment: i've created a new instance with SERVER_PORT 5000, now status has turned to "degraded", this is the log : 30-09-2020 15:24:27 UTC+0200 
WARN
Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Degraded. Initialization completed 45 seconds ago and took 2 minutes. Impaired services on all instances.

Comment: "Following services are not running: application-web-1."